# How to create a blank WinObjc Project in Visual Studio?

Tags: ios, objective-c, visual-studio, winobjc

I can't see any template for that so how to start a new WinObjc Project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't create a blank app in Visual Studio. You create an Xcode project and then convert it to a UWP app by using the vsimporter tool found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/wiki).